# http DELETE errors 400 - trying to find the reason

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the exact same code for "followUser" with a POST request and it works.. for some weird reason delete errors 400

---

Service:

```
this.unFollow = function (to_from, token) {
            $http.defaults.headers.common['auth_token'] =  token;
            return $http.delete($rootScope.endPoint + '/user/follow/', to_from);    
        };
```

Controller:

```
$scope.unFollowUser =function(userid, index){

   var to_from =  {to_user: userid, from_user: $localStorage.CurrentUser.id};
console.log(to_from);
  UserService.unFollow(to_from, $localStorage.CurrentUser.auth_token)
        .success(function (data) {
          $scope.users[index].is_following = false;

          }).
        error(function(error, status) {         
          //alert(status);
          console.log(error);         
      });

}
```

Comment: you need to provide the server code as that's what is generating the error

Comment: i tried in rest client it works @SimonH so i'm giving the benefit of the doubt

Comment: In my experience it has to do with the server, I encountered that issue once when my CORS was not set up right.

Comment: @RVandersteen i'm actually building a hybrid app using ionic framework.. ran it in the emulator (i'm under the impression that emulators take care of CORS issues) and it did NOT work as well... any thoughts

Comment: @RVandersteen and if it's CORS shouldn't it be throwing a 405?? not 400

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're calling `$http.delete(url, options)`, you're not using a valid options object. Maybe try calling it like this:

`$http.delete($rootScope.endpoint + '/user/follow', { data: to_from } );`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http